# Selenium Python can I sort a list of web elements alphabetically

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of web elements.  I would like to sort it alphabetically.
There is no sort function for the data type of web elements.
I got the following error when i tried sort:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore Regression Test\ClearCore - Regression Test\TestCases\DataPreviewsPage_TestCase.py", line 375, in test_a2_sort_data_preview
    print data_previews_page.compare_lists_2()
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501 Regression Test\ClearCore - Regression Test\Pages\data_previews.py", line 610, in compare_lists_2
    sortedTable = DataPreviewsPage.column1_list_before_sort.sort() # This table holds the data previews name in sorted order of what it should be
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

My code snippet is:

```
class DataPreviewsPage(BasePage):
            column1_list_before_sort = None # This list will hold the data from col1 before ClearCore has done the sort.  This list will then be sorted into ABC order.  We can then use it to compare with the list after ClearCore has done the sort

def compare_lists_2(self):
        sortedTable = DataPreviewsPage.column1_list_before_sort.sort() # This table holds the data previews name in sorted order of what it should be
        sortedList = DataPreviewsPage.list_after_ClearCore_has_sorted # This compares the sort with the expected sort (expected sort = sortedTable)
        for item in sortedTable:
            print sortedTable[item]
            print sortedList[item]
```

the method which returns the list of web elements is:

```
def get_table_column_1_values_into_a_list_before_ClearCore_has_done_the_sort(self):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_data_previews_ct_fields_body')))
            table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_data_previews_ct_fields_body')))
            rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
            return [row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1].text for row in rows] # returns the data preview name from col1 for each row
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            print e
            return False
```

How can I sort the list of web elements alphabetically?
The web elements variable is "column1_list_before_sort", I would like to sort this one.

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your cutom comparator to sort a list of object in your custom way, example

```
def comparator(e1, e2):
    return e1.text > e2.text

array.sort(comparator)
```

However, I think the problem is the value of column1_list_before_sort .Since the error is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort'`, it mean nothing inside `column1_list_before_sort`.